# Graph Client - Mapping String Array to List in React Issue

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm returning an array of text using Graph Client and mapping over a list. The issue is the list is lumping them all together into a paragraph instead of breaking each one out into a list item. This works properly if I pull my data from a local array. I tried indexing the map to no avail. Any ideas?

Array from GraphCMS query.

"listItems": [
"Item 1",
"Item 2",
"Item 3"
]

How I'm mapping:

```
{pages.listsection.map((val) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            <li>{val.listItems}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your markup/mapping seems not correct, you should put the static parts like 'div' and 'ul' outside the loop, something like this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {pages.listsection.map((val) =>
      <li>{val.listItems}</li>
    )}
  </ul>
</div>
```